# Test a Facebook App on localhost using a virtual host

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook app that i want to test on my local environment. All time i'm getting this error:

```
Object at URL http://mysite.local/app has og:type of 'website'. 
The property '{namespace}' requires an object of og:type '{namespace}:{object}'.
```

My `<meta>` are these:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{appId}" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="{namespace}:{object}" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://mysite.local/app" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Some title" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.local/img/sample.jpg" />
```

In the settings of my app I have this:

App Domain: `http://mysite.local`

Platform Website (URL): `http://mysite.local/app`

I tried to upload a sample of the app to my prod environment and it worked fine, but i need to test on my local with all the code that has the page and not only with the Facebook app code.

EDIT: I tried the Facebook URL debugger and that's what it says.

**Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed**: Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address.

**Errors That Must Be Fixed**:The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.

**Warnings That Should Be Fixed**:The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags; The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I don't know why it says that i must provide the `og:type` when it provided and the same for the `og:url` and `og:title`

Comment: Looks like your og:type is incorrect and all the og:* after this are ignored.
Fixing your og:type could correct the other issues.

Comment: You can not test Open Graph stuff on your localhost – because the Facebook scraper needs to be able to read the content of those URLs to extract the meta data from it.